# Multidimensional search by combining geospatial indexes

Tags: database, algorithm, search, vector, geospatial

I build application that stores millions of floating point vectors, each vector having ~100 dimensions.  With a query vector, I need to search through these vectors for the k nearest (euclidean) matches.  Run time must be faster than scanning all millions of vectors.  By "vector" I mean in the linear algebra term a list of ~100 floating point numbers i.e. `[0.3, -15.7, 0.004, 457.1, ...]`

I know databases like MySQL and MongoDB provide spatial indexes that work for 2 dimensions.  Is there a way to adapt this to many more dimensions maybe with composite indexes?  Or are there other other data stores support indexes on more dimension?

Comment: When you say "Vector" and "Closest" can you define exactly what you mean? - it is my understanding that a vector is a direction only and as such wouldn't be suitable for spatial indexing.  Are you assuming that all vectors originate from the origin and "Closest" would be measured by the distance between the end points of two given vectors?

Comment: I'll guess that between the two meanings of "vector as sequence of elements" and "vector as direction in a spatial frame" he really means "vector as position in a spatial frame"

Comment: clarified in question.  let me know if this still not claer.

Comment: closest == http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for exact matches, 100 dimensions is a lot. If you are prepared to settle for approximate matches, there is a class of Locality-Sensitive-Hashing schemes. You could generate a hash or series of hash values for you data sets and use an ordinary database or a 2-d spatial database to look for matches based on the hash value. One reference is http://people.csail.mit.edu/indyk/p117-andoni.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

[postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35407280/5757129). It supports any number of dimensions you want. Default size is 100. This can be changed in cubedata.h file during installation. cube operator within postgres has r tree implemented for fast queries.

Comment: please explain a little bit more, how would you use it for given problem, please?

Comment: A vector of 100 size are more can be stored in single cell in postgres. postgres has a eulidean distance calculator. So OP can use this feature available in cube operator to perform knn. To improve response times we can create a index on this column for fast queries.

Answer (score 0):

I can relate to your pain. There is no R-Tree type of implementation in MongoDB, I m not sure if there's one in SQL DBs. I found the following link useful:

http://www.slideshare.net/nknize/mongo-sv-knizefinal