# indexing and query high dimensional data in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, multidimensional-array, indexing, postgresql-9.3

I want to index data in height dimensions (128 dimensional vectors of integers in range of [0,254] are possible):

```
| id |      vector       |
|  1 | { 1, 0, ..., 254} |
|  2 | { 2, 128, ...,1}  |
|  . | { 1, 0, ..., 252} |
|  n | { 1, 2, ..., 251} |
```

I saw that PostGIS implemented R-Trees. So can I use these trees in PostGIS to index and query multidimensional vectors in Postgres?

I also saw that there is a [index implementation for int arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html).

Now I have questions about how to perform a query.
Can I perform a knn-search and a radius search on an integer array?
Maybe I also must define my own distance function. Is this possible? I want to use the [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) (block distance) for my queries.

I also can represent my vector as a binary string with the pattern `v1;v2;...;vn`. Does this help to perform the search?

For example if I had these two string:

```
1;2;1;1
1;3;2;2
```

The result / distance between these two strings should be 3.

Comment: With your example it isn't exactly clear - do you want to see how many elements differ (levenshtein distance) or how much do they differ (Manhattan distance), eg (3-2) + (2-1) + (2-1).

Comment: @hruske: I want to know how much do they differ (manhattan, taxlicab, block)- distance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Perhaps a better choice would be the [cube extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/cube.html), since your area of interest is not individual integer, but full vector.

Cube supports GiST indexing, and Postgres 9.6 will also bring KNN indexing to cubes, supporting [euclidean, taxicab (aka Manhattan) and chebishev distances](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/cube.html#CUBE-OPERATORS-TABLE).

It is a bit annoying that 9.6 is still in development, however there's no problem backporting patch for cube extension to 9.5 and I say that from experience.

Hopefully 128 dimensions will still be enough to get [meaningful results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality).

**How to do this?**

First have an example table:

```
create extension cube;
create table vectors (id serial, vector cube);
```

Populate table with example data:

```
insert into vectors select id, cube(ARRAY[round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000), round(random()*1000)]) from generate_series(1, 2000000) id;
```

Then try selecting:

```
explain analyze SELECT * from vectors
order by cube(ARRAY[966,82,765,343,600,718,338,505]) <#> vector asc limit 10;
                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=123352.07..123352.09 rows=10 width=76) (actual time=1705.499..1705.501 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=123352.07..129852.07 rows=2600000 width=76) (actual time=1705.496..1705.497 rows=10 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (('(966, 82, 765, 343, 600, 718, 338, 505)'::cube <#> vector))
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 26kB
         ->  Seq Scan on vectors  (cost=0.00..67167.00 rows=2600000 width=76) (actual time=0.038..998.864 rows=2600000 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.172 ms
 Execution time: 1705.541 ms
(7 rows)
```

We should create an index:

```
create index vectors_vector_idx on vectors (vector);
```

Does it help:

```
explain analyze SELECT * from vectors
order by cube(ARRAY[966,82,765,343,600,718,338,505]) <#> vector asc limit 10;

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.41..1.93 rows=10 width=76) (actual time=41.339..143.915 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using vectors_vector_idx on vectors  (cost=0.41..393704.41 rows=2600000 width=76) (actual time=41.336..143.902 rows=10 loops=1)
         Order By: (vector <#> '(966, 82, 765, 343, 600, 718, 338, 505)'::cube)
 Planning time: 0.146 ms
 Execution time: 145.474 ms
(5 rows)
```

At 8 dimensions, it does help.

Comment: I also can represent the vector as a binary string(v1;v2;v3...;vn).Is there a option to compare binary strings with manhattan distance?

Comment: Taxicab distance is also known as Manhattan distance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry

Answer (score 12):

(Addendum to selected answer)

For people wanting more than 100 dimensions, beware: there's [a 100 dimensions limit in cube extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/cube.html#AEN176262).

The tricky part is that postgres allows you to create cubes with more than 100 dimensions just fine. It's when you try to restore a backup that it is refused (the worst time to realize that).

As recommended in documentation, I patched cube extension to support more dimensions. I made a docker image for it, and you can look at the Dockerfile to see how to do it yourself, from the [github repos](https://github.com/oelmekki/postgres-350d).

Answer (score 0):

Cross-posting my answer from this similar [DBA Stack Exchange question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/230443):

---

The 2023 answer to this is to use the [pgvector](https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector) extension.

As of this writing, the number of maximum dimensions (defined [here](https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector/blob/master/src/vector.h#L10)) is 16k.

Comment: It's unfortunate that pgvector is not supported in AWS RDS hosted Postgres. Realistically my current project is not going to move off RDS. `cube` is on RDS though.

Comment: @Kobold for sure -- pgvector recommends ([here](https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector#hosted-postgres)) to contact AWS via this [page](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/postgresql/faqs/) about adding extensions. I feel like there's a good chance of pgvector making it in considering the excitement around embeddings right now.

Comment: What's the difference between pgvector and cube?

Comment: cube is limited in the number of dimensions it supports. From the postgres [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/cube.html#id-1.11.7.20.9): "To make it harder for people to break things, there is a limit of 100 on the number of dimensions of cubes". Depending on the use case, it may be enough or not (AI embeddings typically require a few thousand dimensions)

Comment: pgVector is indeed supported now by RDS, AWS posted the announcement recently. See https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/05/amazon-rds-postgresql-pgvector-ml-model-integration/