# PgSQL cube select optimisation

Tags: sql, postgresql, cube

I have a table with +10 million records looking like this:

[image]

Then, using PgSQL CUBE I wish to find all the best matches (distinct by recipe_id), with a maximum distance of 20.

I am currently doing it like below, but I believe it can be done better. In order to get all matches that has a distance below 20, I need to increase the LIMIT (5000 in this sample code) to like 25000, which then impacts the query execution time. With 5000 execution time is ~200ms. With 25000 it's ~1500ms, which is way too much.

Does anyone have an idea on how top optimise it - or maybe point me in a different direction, if there's a cleaner/better/faster approach?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT ON (recipe_id)
        name,
        macros,
        macros <-> CUBE (ARRAY [$gram_protein, $gram_carb, $gram_fat]) AS distance
    FROM (
        SELECT
            R.name,
            IR.macros,
            IR.recipe_id
        FROM
            indexable_recipes IR
            INNER JOIN recipes R ON IR.recipe_id = R.id
        WHERE
            R.id IN(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
        ORDER BY
            IR.macros <-> CUBE (ARRAY [$gram_protein, $gram_carb, $gram_fat])
        LIMIT 5000) AS toplist
WHERE
    macros <-> CUBE (ARRAY [$gram_protein, $gram_carb, $gram_fat]) < 20
ORDER BY
    recipe_id,
    distance) AS distincted
ORDER BY
    distance
```

Comment: Why use a LIMIT at all if you need to set it high enough to catch everything?

Comment: Please show an `explain (analyze, buffers)` for the query, preferably after turning track_io_timing to on.

Comment: Have you tried indexing?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/35407280/13808319

Comment: I have a limit because without, it will take a long time, maybe 30 seconds, to find all matches. I believe it can be possible to get all matches fast, using a different approach. 
 Yes I have an index already, using GIST index, accordingly to the docs, this is optimal for KNN search.